# Clojure multi method dispatch on class of all arguments

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a multi-method which dispatches based on the types of all the arguments passed to it, but I am struggling to figure out how to write such a distpatch fn.

By that I mean, given:

```
(defmulti foo (fn [& args] ...))

(defmethod foo String
  [& args]
  (println "All strings"))

(defmethod foo Long 
  [& args]
  (println "All longs"))

(defmethod foo Number
  [& args]
  (println "All numbers"))

(defmethod foo :default
  [& args]
  (println "Default"))
```

Then we would get:

```
(foo "foo" "bar" "baz") => "All strings"
(foo 10 20 30) => "All longs"
(foo 0.5 10 2/3) => "All numbers"
(foo "foo" 10 #{:a 1 :b 2}) => "Default"
```

Comment: The need for the dispatch on `Number` complicates things because now you're looking for common super types. Is it actually needed?

Answer (score 2):

```
(defmulti foo (fn [& args] (into #{} (map class args))))

(defmethod foo #{String}
  [& args]
  (println "All strings"))

(defmethod foo #{Long}
  [& args]
  (println "All longs"))

(defmethod foo #{Number}
  [& args]
  (println "All numbers"))

(defmethod foo :default
  [& args]
  (println "Default"))
```

Results in:

```
(foo "foo" "bar" "baz") => "All strings"
(foo 10 20 30) => "All longs"
(foo 0.5 10 2/3) => "Default"
(foo "foo" 10 #{:a 1 :b 2}) => "Default"
```

So the Number example doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dispatcher fn:

```
(defmulti foo (fn [& args]
                (let [m (distinct (map type args))]
                  (when (= 1 (count m))
                    (first m)))))
```